# How can i stack a seaborn kdeplot over a real map?

Tags: python, dictionary, seaborn, kernel-density

I've generated a seaborn kdeplot using latitude and longitude of a crime dataset of Chicago and I want to stack it over a real map of the city, which python library is the best to use?

Comment: Might check into Plotly, they have some nice map plotting examples.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the question was about a map of the city that needs to be interacted with but since you mentioned seaborn kdeplot, I guessed not.
This answer only works for a static image.

Having said that, I would save the kdeplot with the same dimension as your image, remove all borders and save it as transparent. Then use pillow to merge

```py
from PIL import Image
import seaborn as sns

# save kdeplot
my_plot = sns.kdeplot(...)

my_plot.set_xlim(0, map_s["width"])
my_plot.set_ylim(0, map_s["height"])
my_plot.set(yticklabels=[])
my_plot.set(xticklabels=[])
my_plot.set(xlabel=None)
my_plot.set(ylabel=None)

plt.gca().set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
plt.box(False)
plt.savefig(filename, transparent=True, dpi=300) # higher resolution

# merge
image1 = Image.open("my_image.jpg")
image2 = Image.open(filename)
image1.paste(image2)
image1.save('new_image.jpg', quality=95)
```